# From css (scss) to Figma

Tags: css, figma

How, I can import css or scss style in to Figma?

I use figma plagin [fromCSS](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/807925991544813159/fromCSS). But it doesn't work for linear or radial grdient like this:

`background: radial-gradient(circle at 75% 30%, #fff 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57) 100%);`

`background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(133, 143, 167, 0) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17));`

So, How can I implement similar gradients in figma?
What are the options to import (or edit) such css styles into Figma?